# How to open a windows 10 application (downloaded from the store) from QT button?

Tags: c++, qt

I manage to open(*.exe) file but I can't open a (*. lnk) file.
I want to open a windows 10 app that I have downloaded from the store.

The code below opens an .exe file, how can it modify it to open .lnk file?

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_App_clicked()
{      QString program = "SMD.exe";  
       QStringList arguments;
       QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess(this);
       myProcess->  start (program,(QStringList) arguments<<""); 
    return ;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried execute `explorer some_file.lnk`?

Comment: @el.pescado: Why would you do that? That's quite overkill.

Comment: @MSalters I would do that because Windows Explorer (not IE) is *the* shell of Windows operating system, and is the program that actually interprets `.lnk` files. Or at least, that's what my reasoning guided by my extremely limited knowledge of MS Windows.

Comment: void MainWindow::on_pushButton_App_clicked()
{      QString program = "C:/windows/system32/cmd.exe";
       QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess(this);
       myProcess->  startDetached (program,QStringList() <<"/C"<<"sag.lnk");
     return ;
}

Answer (score 0):

`QDesktopServices::openUrl` opens files with the default handler, which includes opening `.lnk` files with the shell. You can use that, e.g.:

```
QString shortcut = "C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Accessories\\Notepad.lnk";
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl::fromLocalFile(shortcut));
```